"Sorry, commands are not supported while investigating an exception." when running copilot in Visual Studio 2022
Sometimes, when I ask Copilot something in my Visual Studio 2022 (the one visible when clicking View > "Github Copilot Chat", it responds with:

Sorry, commands are not supported while investigating an exception.

I switch off debugging and I get the same error.
I don't understand what it's telling me?
